# Installed igraph in R and can't call the edge list for a created graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have "successfully" installed igraph within R on Ubuntu 14.04.3. If I create a graph by entering

`g <- graph.formula(1-2)`

then I can call the vertex list via `V(g)` with no problems, but when I try to see the edge list via `E(g)`, I get the error.

`Error in simple_es_index(x,li) : could not find function "anyNA"`

I figured it was a problem with the installation and unistalled both igraph and R, and then reinstalled. However, the problem remains.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i cant reproduce the error. Using ubuntu 14.04, Rv3.2.1, igraphv1.0.1

Comment: What R version are you using?

Comment: I guess you either need a newer version of R or a newer version of igraph.

Comment: I'm using Rv3.0.2. So I guess installing the versions indicated by user20650 ought to do the trick. I will try that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help.